# Help finding a less plug-and-chug solution to gross problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I have the following problem

$$W = + \frac{(3 + 2^{p_{1}})}{2^{(p_1 + p_{2})} - 3^2}$$

Is there a way to prove that if $W$, and all $p_{i}$ are all $\geq 1$ and are integers, that the only solution is $W = 1$ and all $p_{i} = 2$.

I figured that out by just trying values until I got something that gave me an integer W. And it appears that as I make the $p_{i}$ values bigger, the denominator always seems to grow larger faster than the numerator does, hence it will always be a fraction. Thus the only solution can be what I found. But that feels super handwave-y and like there should be a more... real?... way of proving this?

Comment: Are the $p_{i}$ restricted to being positive or nonnegative?

Comment: Yeah your solution is fine. Its very easy to get rid of the handwave if you phrase it in terms of inequalities.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Problem now says $W,p_1,p_2 \ge 1.$ Maybe problem was edited after your comment.

Comment: Since $W\ge 1$ you automatically have $p_1+p_2\ge 4$.  I don't think you're quite out of the woods on the argument for the only solution but there shouldn't be too much left to it.

Comment: @TheBestMagician, I guess if I have it phrased in terms of inequalities, how do I use those inequalities to algebraically show that my solution is the only correct solution? I guess I don't know how else to do it besides just trying numbers and that feels distinctly un-mathy to me.

Comment: Often it's easier to get rid of the fraction entirely: $$2^{p_1+p_2}W -9W= 3+2^{p_1} \implies \\ 2^{p_1}2^{p_2}W -9W=3+2^{p_1}$$ Then show that the left side grows much faster than the other, which is the "handwaving" you did, but formally.

Comment: Ah, that is the important part. Check the small numbers for p first, but then see what happens if they are larger (say greater than some number)

Comment: @abiessu How do I show that, I don't see the logic there... Or maybe I do.  Is that because that's the only solution that can give a positive denominator and therefore a positive solution?

Comment: @EricSnyder I feel a little out of my depth here. I've been working all day and that might be why, not to mention I'm a bit of an amateur so I don't really have the benefit of a formal education. I don't mean to give excuses though. When you say show that the left side grows much faster than the other, what does this mean? How would I show it. And if you don't feel it appropriate to just give the answer, which I totally understand, would you be willing to provide some resources or point me towards books that I might read to learn how to do that. I'm super grateful for everyone's help.

Comment: To show $p_1+p_2\ge 4$ note that $W\ge 1$ and the numerator of the RHS is always positive.  So the denominator must always be positive.  But this is the case only when $2^{p_1+p_2}\gt 9$ which occurs for $p_1+p_2\ge 4$.

Comment: @TinyTim I'm working on turning this into a short answer. Give me 15 min.

Comment: I took a different approach and arrived at a solution.

Comment: Now I feel bad that I can only choose one persons answer, both are wonderful solutions and I'm super grateful for both answers. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our equation can be rewritten:  \begin{align}W&=\frac{(3 + 2^{p_{1}})}{2^{(p_1 + p_{2})} - 3^2}\\
 3+2^{p_1}&=W(2^{p_1+p_2}-9)\\
 2^{p_1}&=2^{p_1}2^{p_2}W-9W-3\\
2^{p_1}(2^{p_2}W-1)&=3(3W-1).
\end{align}
Notice here that the left and right sides can both be written as some $2^m\cdot3^n$.  By the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofArithmetic.html), we must have $$\left\{\begin{align}2^{p_1}&=3W-1\\ 2^{p_2}W-1&=3.\end{align}\right.$$

The second equation is rather easy to solve:  $$2^{p_2}W-1=3\implies2^{p_2}W=4,$$ and since we are given $W,p_2\geq1$, we can only ever have either $(W,p_2)=(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$.

The first equation says that $3W-1$ must be a power of $2$, which means that $3W$ must be odd.  Therefore, $W$ has to be odd, and from the previous conclusion, we now only have $W=1, p_2=2$.  Solving for $p_1$, we have $$3+2^{p_1}=1(2^{p_1+2}-9)\implies12=2^{p_1}(4-1)\implies p_1=2$$ as desired.

---

Edit: a solution to the problem in the comments:

> The equation $$W=\frac{3^2+3\cdot2^{p_1}+2^{p_1+p_2}}{2^{p_1+p_2+p_3}-3^3}$$ can be rewritten as
> \begin{align}
> 2^{p_1+p_2+p_3}W -27W&=9+3\cdot2^{p_1}+2^{p_1+p_2}\\
> 2^{p_1+p_2+p_3}W-2^{p_1+p_2}&=9+3\cdot2^{p_1}+27W\\
> 2^{p_1+p_2}(2^{p_3}W-1)&=3(3+2^{p_1}+9W)
> \end{align}
> Notice that the left has a power of $2$ in $2^{p_1+p_2}$, and so must the right.
> Notice that the right has a power of $3$ with maximum exponent $1$, as we would have been able to factor out more factors of $3$ from the expression but alas.
>
> This shows that $2^{p_3}W-1=3$, bringing us halfway to the same conclusion as above.  Solving for $(W,p_3)$ we have $(W,p_3)=(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$. And just like before, since $3+2^{p_3}+9W$ has to be a power of $2$, it has to be even, and as such, $W$ has to be odd. So we have $(W,p_3)=(1,2)$.
>
> Now we can solve for $p_1$ and $p_2$:
> \begin{align}
> 2^{p_1+p_2}&=3+2^{p_1}+9\\
> 2^{p_1}2^{p_2}-2^{p_1}&=12\\
> 2^{p_1}(2^{p_2}-1)&=12=2^2\cdot3
> \end{align}
> It is trivial to see that $p_1=2$ and $p_2=2$.

Comment: You say that both sides can be written as $3^m 2^n$ but I don't follow this. On the LHS, we have $- 3(3W-1)$ but if $W = 2$, then it would be $-3^1 * 5$ which isn't some $3^m 2^n$. Just wanting clarification on how you come to that.

Comment: +1 for very nice answer. @TinyTim He is using prime decomposition. There is $2^p$ so whatever you get on the right side has to have the same prime factors. It's very clever.

Comment: It is clear that the left side has a power of $2$ (in $2^{p_1}$), and as such, the right side must also have a power of $2$.  Since $3$ cannot be written as a power of $2$, it remains that $3W-1$ must.  Similarly, since the right side has a power of $3$ (in $3$), so must the left.  Obviously $2^{p_1}$ is not the power of $3$, so $2^{p_2}W-1$ must be it.

Comment: That is incredibly clever, I don't know that I would have gotten that. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewChin Why can't we say something like $3W - 1 = 2^{p_{1}} \times k$ Where k is just some other arbitrary number? That would cover the divisibility argument. And would also still seem to fit. Is there a way to prove $k$ must always be $1$? It would mean that $2^{p_{2}}W - 1 = 3k$. How would we show that $k=1$?

Comment: Perhaps it is the fundamental theorem of arithmetic that you don't understand, because I can't imagine the reason behind your immediate question.

Comment: No, I suppose I haven't been entirely clear. This is part of a much larger problem that I've been working on. I'm very much an amateur mathematician and I have no formal education in math beyond calculus and some linear algebra. I've been working on extending the method you used to a larger set of functions, the next function up being

$$W = \frac{3^2 + 3 \times 2^{p_{1}} + 2^{p_{1} + p_{2}}} {2^{p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3}} - 3^{3}}$$

Turns out you can do two partial fraction decompositions like you've done to solve this. But when I showed someone, I was asked what I just asked you.

Comment: Prime decompositions, not partial fraction decompositions. Sorry

Comment: @TinyTim I've made an edit to my answer to address your larger problem.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @AndrewChin I finally understand what I'm trying to ask. Basically, for us to do what you're showing, that has the implication that $3W - 1$ and $2^{p_{2}}W - 1$ are coprime. But these aren't integers, if anything they're more like polynomials. Is there a way to show that these two pieces are or can be coprime? Again, whether or not your respond at this point, I'm super grateful for your help either way.

Comment: @TinyTim But $3W-1$ and all the above algebraic expressions are, in fact, integers, since we have set the conditions that the variables must be integers. Either way, I believe a proof by contradiction should get it done, and is an exercise left to the reader.

Comment: @AndrewChin Fair enough, thank you kindly for your response!

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the fraction, giving:

$$(2^{p_1+p_2}-9)W= 3 + 2^{p_1} \tag1\label1$$

I claim **(A)** that the only solution in positive integers is $W=1, p_1=p_2=2$. It's easily shown that this *is* in fact a solution.

The RHS of ($\ref1$) is always positive. The LHS is positive only if $2^{p_1+p_2}-9$ is positive. Therefore $p_1+p_2 \ge 4$. But if we keep $p_1+p_2=4$ and change $p_1$, the RHS changes without changing the LHS, breaking the equality. Therefore there are no other solutions with $p_1+p_2=4$.

I claim **(B)** that if $p_1+p_2>4$, the following inequality will always hold:

$$2^{p_1+p_2}-9 > 3 + 2^{p_1} \tag2\label2$$

If this is true, $W < 1$ and is not an integer. We rearrange the inequality:

$$2^{p_1+p_2}-2^{p_1}>12$$

If $p_1+p_2 = 5$, the smallest value the expression on the LHS of ($\ref2$) can take is $2^5-2^4 =16$. If $p_1+p_2=6$, the LHS must be greater than $32$, and so forth.

Since this inequality holds, the claim holds. Hence if $p_1+p_2>4, W <1$, and there are no other solutions to the original equation.

Comment: Sorry but this is not right, you seem to have changed what you mean by LHS midway through the argument as if you moved the $2^{p_2}$ term to the left but you didn't state that.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I'm not entirely certain where I was unclear? Moving the $2^{p_1}$ term from right to left didn't change the LHS do you mean after substituting $1$ for $W$? There's language I can probably tighten up in here, I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Let me know if that's clearer @SuzuHirose

Comment: (+1) It looks good to me.